# How can I parse html file using python and beautiful soup from html tag under html tag value?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My html file contains same tag(`<span class="fna">`) multiple times. If I want to differentiate this tag then i need to look previous tag. Tag() under tag(`<span id="field-value-reporter">`). 
In beautiful soup, I can apply only on tag condition like, soup.find_all("span", {"id": "fna"}). This function extract all data for tag(`<span class="fna">`) but I need only which contain under tag(`<span id="field-value-reporter"`)

Example html tags:

```
<div class="value">
    <span id="field-value-reporter">
        <div class="vcard vcard_287422" >
          <a class="email " href="/user_profile?user_id=287422" > 
            <span class="fna">Chris Pearce (:cpearce)
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="value">
    <span id="field-value-triage_owner">
        <div class="vcard vcard_27780" >
          <a class="email " href="/user_profile?user_id=27780"> 
            <span class="fna">Justin Dolske [:Dolske]
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `soup.select`:

```
soup.select('#field-value-reporter a > span') # select for all tags that are children of a tag whose id is field-value-reporter

>>> [<span class="fna">Chris Pearce (:cpearce)</span>]
```

`soup.select` uses css selector and are, in my opinion, much more capable than the default element search that comes with `BeautifulSoup`. Note that all results are returned as list and contains everything that match.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not understand clearly. I want to get only "Chris Pearce" not "Justin Dolske" .

Comment: In that case your css selector should be “#field-value-reporter a span”

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick support